# How to solve this Swift structured concurrency problem?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, swift-concurrency

I have a class written in Swift that looks like this:

```
protocol MessageSubscriber: ObservableObject, Subscriber where Input == Message, Failure == Never {
    func cancel()
}

class MySubscriberClass: MessageSubscriber {
    @Published var data: [MyDataResponse] = []
    
    private var subscription: Subscription?
    
    func cancel() {
        subscription?.cancel()
    }
    
    func receive(subscription: Subscription) {
        self.subscription = subscription
        self.subscription?.request(.unlimited)
    }
    
    func receive(_ input: Message) -> Subscribers.Demand {
        handleMessage(input)
        return .unlimited
    }
    
    func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Never>) {}
    
    @MainActor func handleMessage(_ message: Message) {
        if case .foo(let bar) = message.msg {
            data.removeAll()
            for index in bar.foobar.indices {
                if !bar.foobar[index].isEmpty {
                    data.append(MyDataResponse(parameter: bar.foobar[index], index: index))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A bit of background: This class is used in a view as a `@StateObject` and it works fine (The `@Published data` is updated and shown how I want). However, I got some purple triangle warnings

> Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed ...

so I added `@MainActor` to `handleMessage(_:)` function.

The problem begins after adding `@MainActor` to `handleMessage(_:)` function. Now `receive(_ input: Message)` function is giving an error:

> Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'handleMessage' in a synchronous nonisolated context

Sure, let's wrap the `handleMessage(_:)` call with `Task { @MainActor in handleMessage(_:) }`. This produces a warning

> `Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'MySubscriberClass' in a '@Sendable' closure`.

Note here that I can't mark `receive(_ input: Message)` with `@MainActor` because

> Main actor-isolated instance method 'receive' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement

I can try to go the other way and mark the whole class with `@MainActor`. I believe this is the recommended approach since we are updating the UI from this class. Now I have to mark `cancel()` `receive(subscription: Subscription)` `receive(_ input: Message)` and `receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Never>)` as `nonisolated` because

> Main actor-isolated instance method cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement

Next errors spawn from all the functions I just marked  as `nonisolated`. `

> Main actor-isolated property 'subscription' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context

from inside `cancel()` for example and

> Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'handleMessage' in a synchronous nonisolated context

Let's fix those by wrapping everything with `Task { @MainActor in }`

```
nonisolated func cancel() {
    Task { @MainActor in
        subscription?.cancel()
    }
}

nonisolated func receive(subscription: Subscription) {
    Task { @MainActor in
        self.subscription = subscription
        self.subscription?.request(.unlimited)
    }
}

nonisolated func receive(_ input: Message) -> Subscribers.Demand {
    Task { @MainActor in
        handleMessage(input)
    }
    return .unlimited
}
```

Yet again I have a warning, but this time it comes from the line
`self.subscription = subsription` inside `receive(subscription: Subsription)`

> Capture of 'subscription' with non-sendable type 'any Subscription' in a '@Sendable' closure

What is the correct approach to make this code free of warnings?

`Subscriber` protocol is part of the `Combine` framework. In the view this class is passed as a parameter to a `PassthroughSubject<Message, Never>.subscribe(_:)`

Comment: Somewhere, you are passing an instance of `MySubscriberClass` to some publisher's `subscribe` method. Show us that code.

Comment: You should probably be using GCD, Subscription doesn’t seem to be setup with the new Concurrency so MainActor doesn’t really work. Combine and GCD do not use Actors they use Threads

Comment: Agreed. It is inviting unnecessary headaches to introduce `@MainActor` (and all of the concomitant Swift concurrency checking) in a codebase that is otherwise devoid of Swift concurrency. Generally in Combine, we would use [`receive(on:options)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/receive(on:options:)) to identify the scheduler on which the elements will be received (e.g., `.receive(on: RunLoop.main)`). In the absence of a stand-alone [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it is hard to get too specific…